# How to fetch more than 10000 doc in elastic search 2.4 with jest client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch more than 10000 doc with jest client.

I used scroll feature and use a query size of 50, but my program goes into an infinite loop and in every iteration returns the same 50 doc results.

I guess it is problem with scroll id which I am not passing can some body help.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972508/how-to-get-more-than-10-thousand-documents-at-a-time-from-elasticsearch-using-je

Answer (score 1):

Below is the call to be made to retrieve the first 50 records :

```
POST <host_name>:<port_num>/<index_name>/_search?scroll=1m&size=50
```

As shown above, the size is mentioned as 50 and scroll is 1m, this means that the scroll api will retrieve 50 records per hit and this scroll is available for 1 minute. Also, this api returns a scroll id, which should be used for further retrieval of records. Please find the sample below:

```
POST <host_name>:<port_num>/_search?scroll=1m&scroll_id=<scroll_id>
```

Note : For further scroll api calls, index name need not be mentioned. Only the scroll_id and scroll time is sufficient.

For more information, please refer to the elastic search documentation on scroll api : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html