# Elasticsearch Index Max Result Window Config Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration

when I add this config to `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` in ubuntu vm;

```
index.max_result_window: 1000000
```

after this config when I restart Elasticsearch give me this exception;

```
service elasticsearch status

● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Pzt 2017-12-11 11:52:02 +03; 1s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co   Process: 17997 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${L   Process: 17994 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 17997 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Ara 11 11:51:55 bilal-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Elasticsearch. Ara 11 11:51:55 bilal-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch... Ara 11 11:51:55 bilal-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch. Ara 11 11:52:02 bilal-VirtualBox systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Ara 11 11:52:02 bilal-VirtualBox systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state. Ara 11 11:52:02 bilal-VirtualBox systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior in `elasticsearch 5.x`. 
You are not allowed to set index level settings on node level configuration.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-search-after.html),

> The index.max_result_window which defaults to 10,000 is a safeguard,
>   search requests take heap memory and time proportional to from + size.

If you check elasticsearch log, it will show you something like,

> Found index level settings on node level configuration.
>
> Since elasticsearch 5.x index level settings can NOT be set on the
>   nodes  configuration like the elasticsearch.yaml, in system properties
>   or command line  arguments.In order to upgrade all indices the
>   settings must be updated via the  /${index}/_settings API. Unless all
>   settings are dynamic all indices must be closed  in order to apply the
>   upgradeIndices created in the future should use index templates  to
>   set default values.

**Solution?**

Please ensure all required values are updated on all indices by executing:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings?preserve_existing=true' -d '{
  "index.max_result_window" : "1000"
}'
```

OR,

You can use [Index Template.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-templates.html)

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question at ELK Forum. ELK developer's response: `Use scroll api for this problem.`