# Dumping elastic data into csv or into any NOSQL through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

As we know we can't fetch more than 10000 rows in python from elastic search because of connection error issue. I want data for two hours from my elastic clusterand for every 5 minutes, I am having approx 10000 observation.

1.) Is there is any way if I can just dump the data from elastic search directly into csv or into some Nosql db with more than 10000 count.

I writing my code in python.

**I am having elasticsearch version 5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code for scroll query

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

    es = Elasticsearch()
    es_index = "your_index_name"
    documento = "your_doc_type"


    body = {
            "query": {
            "term" : { "user" : user } 
                 }
            }

    res = helpers.scan(
                    client = es,
                    scroll = '2m',
                    query = body, 
                    index = es_index)
```